# How to pass the header node (?) in the method call if I am using collections framework as shown in the image?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

This is a Java code for single linked list insertion operation.

[image]

Comment: Hey there,

Rather than have folks try to read your handwritten code, taking a little bit of time to write it out here will help folks better recreate your question.

Comment: Sorry this was my first time asking a question. Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to pass the header node inside the 'insertAtFront' method call since you are writing the 'insertAtFront' method inside the SinglyLinkedListClass.

And the header node is already part of the SinglyLinkedListClass structure and we can access it using the '**this**' keyword. Hence you just need to pass the 'data' alone and You can achieve that using the below code,

```java
   public class SinglyLinkedListClass <T> {
     
         public class Node{
         
         T data;
         Node nextNode;
     }
     
      Node headNode;
     
      int size;
      
      public SinglyLinkedListClass() {
         
         this.headNode = null;
         this.size = 0;
     }
     
     public void insertAtFront(T data) {
         
         Node newNode = new Node();
         newNode.data = data;
         if(this.headNode!=null){
         newNode.nextNode = headNode;
         }       
         headNode = newNode;
         size++;
         
         
     }   
     
     }
     
     public class testerclass {
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SinglyLinkedListPractise12<Integer> SL1 = new SinglyLinkedListPractise12<Integer>();
         SL1.insertAtHead(1);
 
     }
     }
```

---